# Beamer: Having more than one bibliography

Tags: beamer, bibtex, bibliographies, subdividing

I want to make a presentation with the `beamer` class and include the Name of the Paper and the authors into my slides. I really like the style in which it is included when using the classical

```
\bibliography{sources1}{}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
```

But I want only one of my sources on each slide and a little bit of explanation afterwards. I have the BibTeX for each of my sources. Is there anyway to convert that to tex code directly and include that code into my slides? Is there a more elegant way? Several .bib files?

Comment: BibTeX generates a `.bbl` with a `\bibitem` for each reference. Each `\bibitem` can be pasted directly into a `.tex` file, inside a `thebibliography` environment. This option requires manual copy and paste, though :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I have understood correctly you want a single reference per slide. Here is a solution using Biblatex.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ref1,
author = "Author, A.",
title = "Title",
journal = "Journal name",
year = 2013}
@book{ref2,
author = "Bauthor, B.",
title = "Book title",
publisher = "publisher",
year = 2013
}
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage[style=trad-plain,
  citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{refsection}
\nocite{ref1}
\printbibliography
Description of the reference
\end{refsection}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{refsection}
\nocite{ref2}
description of the reference
\printbibliography
\end{refsection}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

For each slide we create a `refsection` and we include a `\prinbibliography` for the `refsection`. The `trad-plain` style should mimic the basic `plain` Bibtex style.

[image]

Comment: This does not work with pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/W32TeX). I get the warnings `Citation 'ref1' undefined` and `Empty bibliography` among others.

Comment: @FrederikZiebell Did you compile using the `pdflatex` `biber` `pdflatex` workflow?

Answer (score 4):

If switching to `biblatex` is an option, this is easy possible with the  `\fullcite` command, which internally calls the bibliography driver to typeset a single bibliography entry according to the selected style.

In the example, I have put the references in `\footnotes` (and also used some other `biblatex` citation commands). However, that is not necessary, you may as well use `\fullcite` directly:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ref1,
author = "Alpha, A.",
title = "Title",
journal = "Journal name",
year = 2013}
@book{ref2,
author = "Beta, B.",
title = "Book title",
publisher = "publisher",
year = 2013
}
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  Proof of \citeauthor{ref1}\footnote{\fullcite{ref1}}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  Since \citeyear{ref2}\footnote{\fullcite{ref2}} we know
\end{frame}

% optional
\begin{frame}{Bibliography}
  \printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]